# How to create a custom target that copies a library?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to create a custom target that just copies a library to the LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH. Below is my CMakeLists.txt.

The contents of the MYCOMPONENT folder is mylib.so and CMakeLists.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( MYCOMPONENT )
add_custom_target( MYTARGET
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ./mylib.so ${LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH} )
```

I do the following:

```
cd MYCOMPFOLDER
mkdir build_debug
cd build_debug
cmake -DLIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH=<mycompfolderfullpath>/build_debug/bin ..
```

Now I do an ls of build_debug and I get:

CMakeCache.txt  CMakeFiles  cmake_install.cmake  Makefile

```
ls CMakeFiles/
3.5.1                            CMakeTmp           Makefile2
cmake.check_cache                feature_tests.bin  Makefile.cmake
CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake  feature_tests.c    progress.marks
CMakeOutput.log                  feature_tests.cxx  TargetDirectories.txt
CMakeRuleHashes.txt              MYCOMPONENT.dir

ls CMakeFiles/MYCOMPONENT.dir/
build.make  cmake_clean.cmake  DependInfo.cmake  progress.make
```

From build_debug, "find . -name mylib.so" is nowhere, so of course the "make MYTARGET" fails.  How do I get cmake to properly handle mylib.so?  This is a third party library, we don't build it, the target is to make sure it gets copied to the LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH from this folder so other components can link against it from there.

Comment: If I correctly undestand, copiing fails because there is no `mylib.so` in the build directory. Obviously, you need to specify correct path to the file for successfull copy. **What is a question?** Do you ask where `mylib.so` is located on your machine? Only you know that.

Comment: When doing an out-of-source-tree build, cmake copies files from the source folders to the new tree - mylib.so doesn't get copied, only the CMakeLists.txt file.  That is what I am asking.  Why isn't it copied into the out-of-source-tree path like all the other files in my workspace.  I know where the file is and if this is normal cmake behavior, then I will copy ../mylib.so (relative to the build_debug folder), but it just seems odd that the out-of-source-tree build doesn't copy this file.  It isn't the only binary file in the source tree - we have precompiled shaders too.

Comment: You are wrong: **nothing** is copied from *source tree* to *binary tree* automatically. See carefully: there is no `CMakeLists.txt` in the build tree. In any case, if you want to copy `mylib.so` into some other place, just copy it from the source tree (`${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/mylib.so`).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use relative paths in `-E copy` part. Variables `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`, `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`, `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` are at your disposal.

Comment: Thanks to all for the clarifications.  I had tried using the PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR before there were responses, that worked as well.